# Fallo al insertar un usuario a una unidad organizativa mediante comandos (Win Server 2008)

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, windows-server

buenas tardes.
Me veo obligado a escribir esta duda en el foro ya que me urge solucionarla.
Para un proyecto de una asignatura debo crear un servidor con diferentes estaciones de trabajos y usuarios en cada una de ellas.
Hay dos usuarios de una unidad organizativa que debo crear mediante comandos. La contraseña no debe expirar en ninguno de los dos usuarios.
Una vez que supe que comando tenía que utilizar, me puse manos a la obra para insertar el primer usuario pero me tope con un código de error un poco peculiar del que no hay mucha información en internet.

Comando: `C:\Users\Administrador>dsadd user "cn=dir1,ou=Direccion,dc=alejandro,dc=ortiz,dc=caraballo,dc=com", -samid dir1 -upn dir1@alejandro.ortiz.caraballo.com -pwd dir1_PC_2008 -pwdneverexpires yes`

Salida: `Error code = 0x80005000
Escriba dsadd /? para obtener ayuda.`

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Corriste el comando en consola con permisos de admin?

Comment: Sí, Muchas gracias

Answer (score -1):

por lo que tengo entendido el comando `dsadd user` no es reconocido por el S.O, es más me surgió la duda e intente crear un usaurio con el comando que has mencionado, me sale un error indicandome que el comando no existe como ya suponia.

Por qué no pruebas el siguiente `net user "unombre_usuario" /add` los que se encuentra entre `" "` has de cambiarlos por los nombres de los usuarios. Para poder añadirles contraseñas solo basta con este comando `net user "nombre_usuario" *`, al dar intro te pedira una contraseña para el usuario.

Ojo todos estos comandos tienes que ejecutarlos en el simbolo de sistema como administrador de lo contrario te dara un error.

Bueno espero haberte ayudado aunque un poco tarde.